# redundancy: about 60 or thereabouts

Tags: redundancy

I saw the following sentence in a dictionary.
Does "about" contribute to its meaning? Is the sentence good in terms of style?

> She must be **about** 60 or thereabouts.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Which dictionary? It's annoying when you cite a sentence from a dictionary but don't say which one it was, or which word and definition it was used in. (It's even more annoying when you [don't even mention it's from a dictionary](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/220081) until [after people start answering the question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/220081/one-or-the-other/220102?noredirect=1#comment420393_220102).)

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/thereabouts?q=thereabouts

Comment: This is done deliberately to avoid the Emperor's New Clothes effect. 
It's like medical scientists doing experiments without telling the subjects what exactly they take.

Comment: Yes, and, in medicine, that is considered extremely unethical.

Comment: It is not acceptable to hide relevant information from the volunteers might be gracious enough to answer your question. If you want to test people or run experiments involving their answers, you’ll need to do it elsewhere.

Comment: @J.R. You surely don't want to call double blind experiments "unethical."

Answer (score 1):

**Does "about" contribute to its meaning?** Yes it does it makes the age sound approximate, the author is guessing, what age the subject is.

About as an adverb [Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/about)

**Is the sentence good in terms of style?** That is a matter of taste, some readers may appreciate the use of related pairs, whilst other readers prefer a minimalist approach.

[Related pairs](https://thesaurus.plus/related/around/there_or_thereabouts)